# How to de-flicker (anti-flicker) video?

Tags: vegas-pro

My camera recorded flickering (black flashing) video, maybe due to low-lightened room.  I cant purchase the de-flicker plugins to fix the that video.
is there any free solution to fix that, with plugins or filters?

(p.s. I use **Sony Vegas** )

Comment: I ran into the same issue, but with flickering of a set of monitors with a refresh rate not lining up well with my camera. [The current answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/19681/25348) offered no remedy, nor did I find any useful fx for this. What did help to _some_ degree, was to render the 50fps source to a 29.97fps mp4, should it be of any help to anyone.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, I have found interesting solution:

## Method 1 (bad approach):

- duplicate main video streams and put over the main stream, just off-seting them 1 frame after
- change the opacity of the top video to **31%**, second to **51%**, (leave third at **100%**)

[image]

and the flickering will be gone out. However, it has a downside - the motions will be seen a bit stretched (because of 3-frame repeated).

## Method 2 (Better):

No need to reinvent wheel, there are priced plugins for it. I can't remember but there was a good plugin in market, named "de-flicker" or "anti-flicker" with free trial to test, which did excellent job!

Comment: Very interesting. I'll have to star this one.

Comment: It is working solution! Thanks a lot.